# "To speak in order to be written down by others"

Tags: word-request

A teacher or someone else **speaks** in order to get it **converted** into **text.**

What are the English **verbs** for this?

> The teacher ____ us some beautiful lines.

I am not a native English speaker.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The word is "dictate":

> **[dictate](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/dictate)** (v): Say or read aloud (words to be typed, written down, or recorded on tape), *‘I have four letters to dictate’*

In your example:

> The teacher **dictated** to us some beautiful lines from a poem by Hafiz, which we dutifully copied into our workbooks.

While "dictate" does imply that whatever is dictated should be written down, it's more a *business* term than a *classroom* term.  In this context, a more idiomatic verb might be just "read":

> The teacher **read** us some beautiful lines from a poem by Hafiz, which we dutifully copied into our workbooks.

Note (as Stormblessed mentions) that it's "dictate *to* us", not "dictate us"

Comment: @Kumar In this case, it would be “dictated *to* us”, not just “dictated us”.